# How to run the same SpringBootTests for different applications

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing

I have a SpringBoot multimodule application, something like that:

core
customer1 -> depends on core
customer2 -> depends on core

I want to write integration tests for both, but I don't want to duplicate my core test code. Now I have an abstract class with SpringBootTest(classes = Customer1Application.class) and a lot of test classes, mostly testing the core functionality.

```
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = Customer1Application.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public abstract class AbstractSpringBootTest
{

@Autowired
protected MockMvc                               mockMvc;

@Autowired
protected Validator                             validator;

...
}
```

I want to check if the changes in Customer2 application break something in core functionality, so I want to run these tests with @SpringBootTest(classes = Customer2Application.class) annotation.

How is it possible to configure the application class in the annotation? Is there a way to run the tests with my other application context without manually changing the annotation or duplicating all the steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it will work, but I would try removing `@SpringBootTest` from `AbstractSpringBootTest` and then defining two test classes as follows:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Customer1Application.class)
class Customer1ApplicationSpringBootTest extends AbstractSpringBootTest {}

@SpringBootTest(classes = Customer2Application.class)
class Customer2ApplicationSpringBootTest extends AbstractSpringBootTest {}
```

EDIT:

So I dug around Spring Boot sources and came up with [this solution](https://github.com/Forinil/SBMACT).

Essentially to be able to use system property or property file to configure which @SpringBootApplication is supposed to be tested you need to copy the source of class `org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootConfigurationFinder` to your own test source root and the edit method `private Class<?> scanPackage(String source)` to look something like this (you do not have to use Lombok of course):

```
private Class<?> scanPackage(String source) {
    while (!source.isEmpty()) {
        val components = this.scanner.findCandidateComponents(source);
        val testConfig = System.getProperties();
        val testConfigFile = "test-config.properties";
        val applicationClassConfigKey = "main.application.class";
        try {
            testConfig.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + testConfigFile));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error reading configuration file: {}, using default algorithm", testConfigFile);
        }
        if (testConfig.containsKey(applicationClassConfigKey)) {
            if (!components.isEmpty() && testConfig.containsKey(applicationClassConfigKey) && testConfig.getProperty(applicationClassConfigKey) != null) {
                boolean found = false;
                val configClassName = testConfig.getProperty(applicationClassConfigKey);
                for (BeanDefinition component: components) {
                    if (configClassName.equals(component.getBeanClassName())) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Assert.state(found,
                    () -> "Found multiple @SpringBootConfiguration annotated classes "
                        + components + ", none of which are of type " + configClassName);
                return ClassUtils.resolveClassName(
                    configClassName, null);
            }
        } else {
            if (!components.isEmpty()) {
                Assert.state(components.size() == 1,
                    () -> "Found multiple @SpringBootConfiguration annotated classes "
                                    + components);
                return ClassUtils.resolveClassName(
                     components.iterator().next().getBeanClassName(), null);
            }
        }
        source = getParentPackage(source);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Check the [link](https://github.com/Forinil/SBMACT) for the entire project.

Comment: Yes, it could work, but I would need to duplicate all the test classes. For example:

`@SpringBootTest(classes = Customer1Application.class)
class CoreFunctionXYTestWithCustomer1 extends AbstractSpringBootTest {}

@SpringBootTest(classes = Customer2Application.class)
class CoreFunctionXYTestWithCustomer2 extends AbstractSpringBootTest {}`

Comment: OK, so what if you did not rely on Spring annotations, but rather created ApplicationContext for test manually? Then you could read some sort of configuration file beforehand and determine what configuration class to use that way.

Comment: Yes, something like that would be perfect, but I can't find in google any info how to do that

Comment: I edited my answer to show how you can trick Spring Boot to let you choose @SpringBootApplication class via system property or config file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check?
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Customer1Application.class, Customer2Application.class})

Comment: If I do so, Spring tries to pull up both applications at the same time. This causes conflicts in route mapping and some other problems. I would need a way where I can clearly separate the two apps

Comment: Hmm maybe it's a workaround idea but if you need to fast manually customize your test you can: create test configuration class with @Profile("testprofile"). After that just run test with @AciveProfiles("testprofile") to load beans only from this profile?